# Can you upgrade SAFELY from 3.4.x or 3.5.x to the 3.6.2 release?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.6

Given [the "dance" that is required for the Joomla 3.6.1 upgrade](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5666-the-joomla-3-6-1-update.html), is it possible to Safely update to [the 3.6.2 release](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5667-joomla-3-6-2-released.html) directly from 3.x where X < 6? *(So versions 3.4.x or 3.5.x…)*

Or are extra steps required? (The 3.6.2 release doesn't make it clear.)

Comment: The update should be smooth unlike the 3.6.1 update. Perhaps take a backup of your site and installl it on a subdomain or localhost, and try performing the update there first.

Answer (score 1):

The v3.6.2 release isn't much better than the v3.6.1 release as far as the Joomla update goes (except maybe if you upgrading sites still on PHP 5.3).

The advice at https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5666-the-joomla-3-6-1-update.html still pretty much applies to v3.6.2.

I updated about 20 sites today mostly from v3.5.1 and this is the best I could do:

1. run a backup and copy the backup file offsite
2. update third party extensions to the latest versions first
3. temporarily disable the "System - Backup on update" plugin if you have Akeeba Backup installed (this step probably isn't required any more if you update to Akeeba Backup v5.1.4 first)
4. run the Joomla v3.6.0 update that is offered in the Joomla Update component
5. click on the "Clear Cache" button
6. run the Joomla v3.6.2 update that is offered in the Joomla Update component
7. at the "invalid security token" error, browse back to `/administrator` then go to `Extensions -> Manage -> Database` and click on the "Fix" button
8. re-enable the "System - Backup on update" plugin
9. go to Extensions -> Manage -> Update and update the "Joomla Update" plugin to the latest version (you might need to click on "Clear Cache" and "Find Updates" before the update is offered)

Answer (score 1):

Due to debugging a SQL issue I've just updated my test server install from 3.5.? to 3.6.2 using the Update button. I had no issues at all, even with all the half-baked components and modules I had installed on the test site & corresponding database already - I wouldn't have known there were issues with earlier versions until I saw your question, the update was smooth and painless and all my own extensions work as intended.

Obviously your own experience will depend on the extensions you have installed and I'd make sure to test it out on a development server first, but Joomla itself seems to be updating fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use Watchful.li to manage my sites.  I like to give props when something just works.  I literally updated 50 sites to Joomla 3.6.2 today with no issues (other than 2 non-related extension problems).   https://watchful.li/